# Как избежать дублирования кода при составлении массива, если от условия зависит только одно поле

Tags: php, массивы

Надо добавить строку в массив если $_POST['newpass'] не пустое.
Пока сделал так:

```
if($_POST['newpass'] == '')
{
 // Тут функция записи в файл
 filewriter(System . Db, upXMLer($db, array(
                'sitename' => $_POST['webname'], 
                'lang' => $_POST['lang'], 
                'theme' => $_POST['theme'])));
}
 else
{
 filewriter(System . Db, upXMLer($db, array(
                'sitename' => $_POST['webname'],
                'pass' => password_hash($_POST['newpass'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
                'lang' => $_POST['lang'], 
                'theme' => $_POST['theme'])));
}
```

Массив достаточно длинный и как то if else для этого наверно не подходит.
Есть ли вариант попроще?

Answer (score 0):

Это хороший вопрос. И ответ на него очевиден - стоит только сформулировать проблему четко.
Это вообще очень важное качество для программиста - умение формулировать проблему. Это не только позволяет сразу увидеть решение но и в самых сложных случаях позволяет найти ответ в гугле за 3 секунды.

Я поменял заголовок вопроса и решение тут же становится ясно - заранее сформировать массив из полей, попадающих в него в любом случае, а в условии добавлять уже только изменяемые. Плюс из условия убирается выполнение кода. В общем, мы убираем из условия все повторяющиеся части.

```
$data = [
    'sitename' => $_POST['webname'], 
    'lang' => $_POST['lang'], 
    'theme' => $_POST['theme'],
];
if($_POST['newpass'])
{
    $data['pass'] => password_hash($_POST['newpass'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
}
filewriter(System.Db, upXMLer($db, $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо так просто :)
Добавлю что правильнее так:

```
$data = ['pass' => password_hash($_POST['newpass'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT),];
```

Comment: 1) Если ответ вам помог - отметьте его как решение. Вам не сложно, а ответившему приятно. 2) Нет, при вашей постановке задачи так не правильнее. Правильнее у Ипатьева в ответе

Comment: Как отметить решение вопроса? Есть только ссылки 
поделиться править.